# Building Facebook With Latest iOS SDK for ARC and Multiple Developers

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm attempting to upgrade from Facebook SDK 2.0 to 3.0 and I'm having basically the same issue as is mentioned in this thread: [XCode & Facebook IOS SDK - Instructions incorrect](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11862669/xcode-facebook-ios-sdk-instructions-incorrect) but with a slightly different goal I think.

I'm using the instructions here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

When I try to build the static library, I get a "no such file or directory" message. I checked, and sure enough, there is no build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh file in the "scripts" directory when I try to execute it.

Here's my dilemma. We have multiple developers on the project (and some other members who basically know how to pull down and build within Xcode but that's about it), and I don't want to require all of them to install the Facebook SDK. Same for a build machine (though in that instance I suppose we could install the SDK directly on the build machine).

It sounds like building a static library has been effectively deprecated, or maybe I'm missing something, but what I really need to just get all the pertinent code into our repository, and in a form in which anyone can **just pull it down and build**. Is this possible with the 3.0 SDK, and if so, what would be the steps to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the Facebook SDK 3.1 (latest from 3.0) you should not follow the old instructions, instead check these instructions out:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/